# Escaping javascript in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am using razor to generate a javascript in razor loop however i am unable to use variable in it

This is my code

```
<script>
$(function () {

     @Html.Raw("$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.DG['@i'].status_code)').on('change', function () { Dg_Calculate('@i');});")
     @Html.Raw("$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.DG['@i'].belasting)').on('change', function () { Dg_Calculate('@i'); });")
     @Html.Raw("$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.DG['@i'].max_belasting)').on('change', function () {Dg_Calculate('@i');});")

      $("#txtDate").datepicker();
 });

 function Dg_Calculate(item) {
 alert(item);
 }
</script>
```

Here in the generated code "@i" is coming as it is and not value of "i"

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you give the whole razor page code

Comment: I am assuming that Dg1_Calculate is a Javascript function?

Comment: @MattStannett yup it is

Comment: @Ammar updated code

Comment: Your string that is passed to `@Html.IdFor` is treated as `string`, so using `@` inside it means nothing. Instead of generating javascript listeners for each element by their `id`, you can simply use `class` instead, and write something like `$('.some-class').on('change', Dg1_Calculate);`

Comment: @Ammar i also want to pass value of i to function like call Dg2_Calculate if i is 2 etc..

Comment: @BlazeMathew why not just have a generic Dg_Calculate function that takes the index as a parameter? I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Ammar please help with my updated code

Comment: @MattStannett did like u told. now how to have this code generated with values for "i"

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string that is passed to `@Html.IdFor` is treated as `string`, so using `@` inside it means nothing.

You can alternatively use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), and your code should look something like:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        @for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            @Html.Raw($"$('#{Html.IdFor(m => m.DG[i].status_code)}').on('change', function () {{ Dg_Calculate({i});}});")
            @Html.Raw($"$('#{Html.IdFor(m => m.DG[i].belasting)}').on('change', function () {{ Dg_Calculate({i});}});")
            @Html.Raw($"$('#{Html.IdFor(m => m.DG[i].max_belasting)}').on('change', function () {{ Dg_Calculate({i});}});")
        }

        $("#txtDate").datepicker();
    });

    function Dg_Calculate(item) {
        alert(item);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve - whenever any of the 14 elements that has the following classes `status_code`, `belasting`, `max_belasting` you want to call the `Dg1_Calculate` function.

If this is the case then this is more easily achieved in Javascript itself rather than trying to write Razor code to generate Javascript. It looks like you're using jQuery  syntax so how about something like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.status_code,.belasting,.max_belasting').on('change', function()
        {
             var index = $('.status_code,.belasting,.max_belasting').index(this);
             Dg_Calculate(index);
        });

       function Dg_Calculate(index) {
          console.log(index)
       }
    </script>
}
```

You will probably also need to include the jQuery library above your script section/in your layout template if it is not already done, something like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

For reference see the [Javascript Libraries](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-using-javascript-with-ajax-and-razor-partial-views) section, and [jQuery multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).